# Java Output Integers to File

Tags: java, file-io

Im trying to output an integer array to a file and have hit a snag. The code executes properly, no errors thrown, but instead of giving me a file containing the numbers 1-30 it gives me a file filled with [] [] [] [] [] I have isolated the problem to the included code segment.

```
try
       {
       BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath));
       int test=0;
       int count=0;
        while(count<temps.length)
        {
          test=temps[count];  
          bw.write(test);
          bw.newLine();
          bw.flush();
          count++;
        }
       }
       catch(IOException e)
       {
           System.out.println("IOException: "+e);
       }
```

filepath refers to the location of the output file. temps is an array containing the values 1-30. If anymore information is necessary, i will be happy to provide.

Comment: Can you confirm that you want to have a "text" file containing human-readable data, rather than a binary file?

Comment: The output file should be a human-readable "text" file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BufferedWriter.write(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29) writes the character value of the int, not the int value.  So outputing 65 should put the letter `A` to file, 66 would print B...etc.  You need to write the `String` value not the int value to the stream.

Use [BufferedWriter.write(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28java.lang.String%29) instead

```
bw.write(String.valueOf(test));
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) or [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) instead:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(filePath, true); // true for auto-flush
int test = 0;
int count = 0;
while(count < temps.length)
{
    test = temps[count];  
    ps.println(test);
    count++;
}
ps.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you are using the [`BufferedWriter.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29) method.  What is confusing you is that while the method signature indicates it's writing an `int`, it's actually expecting that int to represent an encoded character.  In other words, writing `0` is writing `NUL`, and writing `65` would output `'A'`.

From [Writer's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28int%29) javadoc:

> ```
> public void write(int c) throws IOException
> ```
>
> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

A simple way to correct your problem is to convert the number to a String before writing.  There are numerous ways to achieve this, including:

```
int test = 42;
bw.write(test+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the integer array to a byte array and do something like this:

```
public void saveBytes(byte[] bytes) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
 try (BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filepath))) {
   out.write(bytes);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You write the number as an Integer to the file, but you want it to be a string.
change `bw.write(test);` to `bw.write(Integer.toString(test));`